# Odoo: how to search a parent_id and its all child in product.category

Tags: python, class, model, odoo

I want to, when the user selected (through Many2one field) a category, I need to find its related `parent_id` for `Brands` to add a domain filter on another Many2one field to have related child entries of these Brands. As I am beginner I failed to how to do this.

Suppose Many2one field `category_id` here, user will select a category from first three entries, now we know that user wants to add an Electronics related item then system should populate Many2one field `brand_id` on Electronics related Brands (except All / Electronics / Brands) to select from below last 2 entries here in All / Electronics.

```
All / Electronics / Personal Computers
All / Electronics / Personal Computers / Laptop
All / Electronics / Personal Computers / Desktop
... 
...
All / Electronics / Brands
All / Electronics / Brands / HP
All / Electronics / Brands / IBM
```

There are more brands in this model (table data) like:

```
All / Foods / Brands
All / Foods / Brands / Hershey
All / Foods / Brands / Heinz
All / Foods / Brands / Oreo
...
All / Services / Brands
All / Services / Brands / IBM Garages
All / Services / Brands / Telos MNS
All / Services / Brands / Relia Quest
...
```

My custom Model class:

```
class OrderItems(models.Model):
    _name = 'tests.orderitems'
    _description = "Tests Order Items"

    store_id = fields.Many2one('tests.stores', string="Store", ondelete='cascade')
    order_id = fields.Many2one('tests.testsorders')
    categry_id = fields.Many2one('product.category', string="Category",
                                 domain="[['complete_name', 'not like', '%Brands%']]")
    items_id = fields.Many2one('tests.storeitems', string="Item",
                               domain="[['categs_id', '=', categry_id]]")
    brand_id = fields.Many2one('product.category', string="Brand",
                               domain="[['complete_name', 'like', '%Brands%']]")
    unit_id = fields.Many2one('tests.units', string="Unit")
    quantity = fields.Integer(string="Quantity", required=True, default=1)
    rates = fields.Float(string="Rate", default=0)
    size = fields.Char(string="Size")
```

Please help, how I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your brand_id domain to:

```
categ_name = fields.char('Category Name', related='categry_id.complete_name')
brand_id = fields.Many2one('product.category', string="Brand",
                           domain="[('complete_name', 'like', categ_name),('complete_name', '!=', categ_name)]")
```

Here's the preview:

[image]

Comment: thanks @SDBot but its showing empty list, nothing to select.

Comment: oh ok, my bad, i updated the code, can you try that? make sure to include the categ_name field in the view (set it to invisible if you want)

Comment: thanks for your interest to help me... but unfortunately, still this not working (still showing empty list), also added field in its view (xml) as per requirement. i wants to show only related Brands when user selected a Catedgory. user can select one as All / Foods / Bakery and list should contain the child records of All / Foods / Brands. same for other rows of any level. regards

Comment: can you show me your xml file? i think you might have added domain there

Comment: in Add Comment it is not possible, i have to show it in Answer section here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227989/discussion-between-sdbot-and-oralover).

Comment: no, not yet, you were right the level field didn't help, still failed, i can't figure it out how to achieve it. anyway, there is another question i will ask here. regards

Comment: I think the solution above worked, I added preview, if it wasn't working on your machine, then the problem is not the filter but rather the field itself, please make sure the field show full list without any filter applied

Answer (score 0):

@SDBot, the xml code for this particular model is here...

```
            <notebook>
                <page string="Order Items">
                    <field name="order_ids">
                        <tree editable="bottom" string="Order Items">
                            <field name="store_id"/>
                            <field name="categry_id"/>
                            <field name="items_id"/>
                            <field name="categ_name"/>
                            <field name="brand_id"/>
                            <field name="unit_id"/>
                            <field name="quantity"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </page>
            </notebook>
```

Model where added a field categ_name and a domain in brand_id

```
class OrderItems(models.Model):
    _name = 'tests.orderitems'
    _description = "Tests Order Items"

    store_id = fields.Many2one('tests.stores', string="Store", ondelete='cascade')
    order_id = fields.Many2one('tests.testsorders')
    categry_id = fields.Many2one('product.category', string="Category",
                                 domain="[['complete_name', 'not like', '%Brands%']]")
    items_id = fields.Many2one('tests.storeitems', string="Item",
                               domain="[['categs_id', '=', categry_id]]")
    categ_name = fields.Char('Category Name', related='categry_id.complete_name')
    brand_id = fields.Many2one('product.category', string="Brand",
                               domain="[('complete_name', 'like', categ_name),('complete_name', '!=', categ_name)]")
    unit_id = fields.Many2one('tests.units', string="Unit")
    quantity = fields.Integer(string="Quantity", required=True, default=1)
    rates = fields.Float(string="Rate", default=0)
    size = fields.Char(string="Size")
```