# Odoo v14: how can I get parent value in the creation of child?

Tags: python, odoo, relationship, onchange

Model is `product.category`, *want to inherit and add a field `level`* to add the levels to find which level record I want.

We knew that by default (as recommended) that first entry `*All*` here should present to start the parent child relations.

When the user creates a new category and select *All* as its parent, we knew that its level is 1, and we can add 2, programmatically it should be parent_level + 1 ... so we can add levels of any depth.

I don't know how to code it, so please help me for the below *onchange function* (or any other better approach, please specify), guide/modify it to achieve what I want to have.

```
@api.onchange(parent_id):
def _onchange_parent_id(self):
  find the level of parent here...
  self.level = parent_level + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if i understand your question correctly, but if you just want a level to your category and provided the parent field name is parent_id:

```
level = fields.Integer('Level', compute='_compute_level')

@api.depends('parent_id')
def _compute_level(self):
    for record in self:
        record.level = (record.parent_id.level or 0) + 1
```

Comment: thanks, i have inheritted product.category, added a field 'level', for entry 'All' updated level 1 manually, modified model as per your given code here, first in level.parent_id.level it is (pycharm) saying that first occurance of 'level' is not recognised, modified it to "self.parent_id.level", restart server, upgrade app, run it and create a new entry Transport select All as its parent, saved and check, the value for level is still null.

Comment: @Oralover, it should be record.parent_id.level not level.parent_id.level, i updated my answer

Comment: thanks @SDBot, will check and confirm. be blessed :)

Comment: modified and checked but still not working.

Comment: did you store the compute field? if so you have to recompute, otherwise that should be working

Comment: btw what do you mean by not working? wrong result or no result?

Comment: if the compute methos is running then there is no way the result is null, can you make sure to not store the compute field for now? (set store=False) then upgrade and go to your model view see if the field has any value it should be at least have the value of 1, null is simply impossible

Comment: my bad, i extremely very sorry, i failed to store the compute field, its working now... really appreciate your struggle and much thankful to achieve this, now may be with this level, i can achieve what i asked previous topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65931511/odoo-how-to-search-a-parent-id-and-its-all-child-in-product-category/65934127?noredirect=1#comment116606591_65934127

Comment: that's ok, i am happy to help, but i doubt this field will help much in your previous topic about the filtering of brand.